# can we read phone contacts of one mobile device to the application of other mobile over bluetooth using android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, mobile-application

I have installed an infotainment application developed using android in one device where I have connected that device to the mobile using Bluetooth and I want to read all the contacts and call logs of the connected mobile into the application of that device. (like car infotainment screen when connected to the mobile).

Comment: please anyone help me out regarding this query

Comment: Your application should be able to send and receive data over Bluetooth and your app should ask for Contact permission from the user and it should be installed in both devices obviously. :)

Comment: Bluetooth PBAP (phonebook access profile) client implementation exists in Android source code repository but generally is not included in smartphne firmware. You can get it there (with some dependencies).